# update table from a sub from in access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a database of a bank, in access.
I have table of accounts, which contain the account number, balance and some other things.
In addition I have a table of the customers and their details.
I connect between customer and his account, by another table of accounts owner.

My question is when I use forms, I have a form of customers, which contain subform of accounts.
Now if I want to add in that way account to specifc customer, what that happen
is that the account create, but the accounts owner table is not update.
So I have no way to connect the new account with the customer.

Can you help me what that?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a many-to-many relationship. However, subforms are only for one-to-many. The subform should be linked to the "accounts owner" table and not the "accounts" table.

This blog link does the same as you in an Order/Details scenario:

http://ms-access-tips.blogspot.ca/2012/02/creating-form-for-many-to-many.html

Comment: But if I link the customer table to the accounts order, I won't be able to add new account. I would be able to add to the customer only existing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create relationships in Access to define how the tables are related.  I have Access 2003 in front of me, so I would click on Tools, and then Relationships (can't remember how to do it in Access 2007 off the top of my head).  When you link the Customers and Accounts tables together, make sure you check the box labeled "Enforce Referential Integrity".  That should add a new record for you in the Customer table when you add a record in the Account table.